# Force an energy profile during gameplay?

Tags: windows-10, power, overclocking

So by default I have an energy profile that set maximum cpu power at 50%, and that's fine while i am browsing and doing other simple things.

But while I am playing, 50% max of CPU isn't enough. Is there any way to switch automatically energy saving profiles while i am playing?

Comment: You can use the command Powercfg /setactive {guid} to change power settings profiles. If you create a batch file to launch your game and include that before and after the start of the game, and then change the shortcut to that batch file, you can make it work for one game.

Comment: did you try enabling [game mode](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-disable-game-mode-windows-10-creators-update)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are interested in this free app.

PowerPlanSwitcher lets you quickly change Power Plans in Windows 10

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-power-plans-powerplanswitcher

Comment: great it sounds good